# HANA .NET client fails when user password is about to expire

Tags: .net, hana

It seems the .NET client is unable to handle properly the message returned form the HANA server when the user password is about to expire. Anyone worked around this?

Comment: Can you add a minimal code example that reproduces the issue to help clarify the problem and get you an anwser?

Answer (score 0):

How do you currently try to get the `WARNING` message from SAP HANA? Based on the  [SDK API Reference](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.01/en-US/d1964d546d6110149367fd63aaba6c26.html)  this should be done with the `HanaError` class.